# Strong multiplicity one theorem for new forms of different levels

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms, hecke-algebras

Let $f, g$ be newforms of level $N_f, N_g$ (possibly different) with $N_f, N_g |N$, and assume that they have same eigenvalue for Hecke operators $T_p$ with $(p, N) = 1$. Then $N_f = N_g$ and $g = cf$ for some constant $c$.

My friend gave one proof using the Galois representation attached to these forms and Carayol's theorem on the conductor of these representations, but this seems a little overkill for me. I wonder if there's a simpler proof for this. (It seems that there's a proof in Miyake's book using $L$-function).

---

Here's the proof. We will assume strong multiplicity one theorem for new forms *of the same level*. So the only thing we need is to prove $N_{f} = N_{g}$. Let $\rho_{f, \ell}, \rho_{g, \ell}$ be the attached $\ell$-adic Galois representations. Since $\mathrm{tr}(\rho_{f, \ell}(\mathrm{Frob}_{p})) = a_{p}(f) = a_p(g) = \mathrm{tr}(\rho_{g, \ell}(\mathrm{Frob}_{p}))$ for all $p\nmid \ell N$, we have $\rho_{f, \ell} \simeq \rho_{g, \ell}$. Carayol's theorem states that the $\ell$-free part of $\mathrm{cond}(\rho_{f, \ell})$ and $N_{f}$ are the same, so by choosing different $\ell$'s, we get $N_{f} = N_{g}$.

Comment: What was your friend's argument? I'm worried that using Galois representations might be circular: without strong multiplicity one, how do you know that, if $\rho_f\simeq\rho_g$, then $f = g$? Perhaps there's a way to circumvent this though.

Comment: What version of strong multiplicity one are you happy to assume?

Comment: @Mathmo123 I'm assuming strong multiplicity one for new forms of the same level. I add some details of the proof.

Comment: The strong multiplicity one theorem is really an automorphic statement, and doesn't depend on the level: it just says that if $\pi$ and $\pi'$ are two automorphic representations such that $\pi_p\simeq \pi'_p$ for all but finitely many primes, then $\pi\simeq \pi'$. So just take the automorphic representations attached to $f$ and $g$, and use the fact that $a_p$ determines $\pi_p$ for good primes $p$.

Comment: @Mathmo123 I see. Is it possible to prove it only with multiplicity one result for modular forms (new forms of the same level)?

Comment: Once you know that they are eigenfunction of all (level $N_j$) Hecke operators plus the $z\to -N_j/z$ involutions then the L-function proof is easy: $L(f,s)=h(s) L(g,s)$ for some quotient of two Dirichlet polynomials, the functional equation implies that $h(s)$ is a constant